# Unit Test for setTimeOut in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I just start learn new things about unit test in Angular. I have read some article, but I am still stuck when I implement create test case for setTimeOut condition. I have function in .component.ts

```
  resetDropdown(elementId) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (elementId !== 'free-text-head-'.concat(this.id)) {
        if (elementId !== this.id) {
          if (this.isFreeTextEnabled && elementId !== 'free-text-body-'.concat(this.id)) {
            this.isFreeTextEnabled = false;
            this.assignSearchKeywowrd(this.value, this.config.displayKeyMain, this.config.selectedKey);
            this.isFreeTextSearchEmpty = false;
            this.listData = this.options;
          }
        }
      }
    }, 100);
  }
```

How I do create this one in jasmine? Thank you guys for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO community, justTrustMe! It would be beneficial for you and community to finish the introductory tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour. It would help to increase your chances to get help. And would give you a badge (: Probably some points as well, which would give you more permissions here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fakeAsync` + `tick` are very handy for this.

```js
describe('#resetDropdown when isFreeTextEnabled is true and argument is nor 'free-text-head-'.concat(component.id), nor 'free-text-body-'.concat(component.id), nor component.id', ()=>{
   const mockOptions = {someOption: 'someValue'};
   beforeEach(() => fakeAsync({
      component.options = mockOptions;
      component.isFreeTextEnabled = true;
      component.id = 'something not similar to argument';

      component.resetDropdown('something not similar to component.id');
      tick(100);
   }))
   it(`sets isFreeTextEnabled to false`, () => {
      expect(component.isFreeTextEnabled).toEqual(false)
   });
   it(`sets isFreeTextSearchEmpty to false`, () => {
      expect(component.isFreeTextSearchEmpty).toEqual(false)
   });
   it(`sets component.listData to component.options`, () => {
      expect(component.listData).toEqual(mockOptions)
   });
});
```

It's a useful practice to keep only one expect in one `it`. Makes it easy to recognize what is wrong when a test fails. When there are several lines like `expect(something).toEqual(true)` and the failure message says `expected false to be true` it takes time to find out which one among the `expect`s fails.

PS: `setTimeout` is a smell in Angular. There could be a better solution. It's difficult to say what is smelling from this short code excerpt.